# Multi-line equations with explanations on some lines

Tags: equations

I would like something like this:

```
STH
= STH       REASONS Explained.
= STH       LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG
        REASON
= STH.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you use the [amsmath](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=amsmath) package then this can be done using the `align` (or `align*` if you don't want the equations numbered) environment together with the `\text` command for the text.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A &= B \\
&= C && \text{Because of D} \\
&= D && \text{But beware of E} \\
&&& \text{Some more on that}
&= F
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Result (note that the actual result will be centred on the page):

[image: aligned mathematics]

To get the alignment as you have it, you would have:

```
&A \\
&= B \
```

at the start.

The amsmath package is loaded by default if you use one of the classes from the AMS, such as amsart.

Comment: My reason bits are coming out right-aligned and I don't see how to left-align them :(

Comment: Ok, i figured this out: "reason" bits come out right-aligned if preceded by a single "&" and left-aligned if preceded by double "&&."

Answer (score 8):

Loop Space answer works well, however, it requires manually splitting the text. This is not very convenient.

A more convenient way is to use `\parbox`

Following his/her example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A &= B \\
&= C && \text{Because of D} \\
&= D && \parbox[t]{5cm}{
          Some long description here that will split 
          automatically and then force a fourth line \\ 
          Another line here} \\
&= F
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As a suggestion, here is what can be done with `witharrows`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows*}[wrap-lines]
A & = B \Arrow{because of D} \\
  & = C \Arrow{some long explanation with automatic line breaking} \\
  & = D \\
  & = F
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Can it have forced line breaks

Comment: @Xanlantos: Yes, with the classical command with two backslash.