# The multi-line equation with explanation is too wide

Tags: spacing, equations, align

[The original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/multi-line-equations-with-explanations-on-some-lines) provides a good answer for how to add explanations to the multi-line equations. However, my problem is that the explanations have too long space to the corresponding equations, so they often extend to the margin of page. How can I narrow the space between the equations and their explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the odd occasion where your `align` comment spans multiple lines, consider using a `[t]`op aligned `\parbox` of fixed width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A &= B \\
  &= C && \text{Because of D} \\
  &= D && \parbox[t]{0.7\linewidth}{\raggedright\lipsum*[2]} \\
  &= F
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `\tag{}` for this question?

Comment: @Karl'sstudents: The `\tag` will appear on the same line as the math content.

Comment: @Werner: excuse me. the explanation in your case seems to come from the external document. I tried to delete the \raggedright\lipsum*[2] and replace it with my own explanation, but the explanation will extend to nowhere. Could you explain it further? I am really new to latex...

Comment: @user26362: What does your explanation look like? Is it paragraph text? You could [edit your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/106437/edit) to include what you've tried thus far.

Comment: @Werner: I thought I made a silly move: keep typing "afadfadfd" so the explanation will extend out. But, if I tried to type some complete sentences, they became a paragraph. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the `alignat` environment. You can find the details in [mathmode.pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
A &= B \\
  &= C &\quad& \text{Because of D} \\
  &= D && \text{But beware of E} \\
  &    && \text{Some more on that} \\
  &= F &&
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```