# Multi-line explanation including math and text next to equation in Overleaf

Tags: math-mode, align, overleaf, parbox

I saw two answers[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336881) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106441) suggesting the use of `\parbox` in an `\align*` environment in order to type some long explanation next to an equation progression. I want this explanation to include a math expression.

If I try adding the math expression in between dollar-signs the compiler screams at me. If I try to end the `\parbox` before the math expression and start another right after it - I get (as I should) two boxes, one next to each other and the text does not appear as a continuation of itself. If I want the expression as a text - for some reason the underscore forces a math-mode to the expression and drags all the trailing text into this mode as well.

How can I include a math expression in the explanation?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A &= B \\
&= C && \text{Having }x_2+5\text{ here is fine} \\
&= D && \parbox[t]{5cm}{
          But having it here cannot 
          be achieved via dollars $x_2+5$ around it} \\ %ERROR: unclosed open { found at $    
                                                        %       unexpected $ after \begin{align*}
&= E && \parbox[t]{5cm}{
          nor via the same trick as the text command, 
          i.e. }x_2+5\parbox[t]{5cm}{ like so}\\
&= F && \parbox[t]{5cm}{
          and even if I give up and want it formatted 
          as text it decides for me to change to math 
          mode all the text x_2+5 appearing after it}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

result: (note that the one that looks fine raises a compilation error which I added next to it above)
[image: result of the given code]

EDIT: After comments and an answer saying others don't get the same error - I should probably add that I work in Overleaf. While checking the same code in another website (papeeria.com) I didn't get an error - so I'm suspecting it's something to do with Overleaf itself, rather than Latex. Here's how the error looks there:

[image: screenshot of overleaf error]

I would still like not to have this error - so if there's any advice I would like to know. Otherwise I'll just file a bug report :)

Comment: I get no error if I remove the E and F parts.

Comment: What happens if you change the two instances of `x_2+5` that are currently not in math mode to `$x_2+5$`?

Comment: @Mico adding dollar-signs around the one at the end (the other one is already in math-mode as its outside of the `\parbox`) just raises the error there as well.

Comment: I edited to include a print-screen of the error in Overleaf, as it seems like several people don't get it outside of Overleaf. I'm guessing it's a bug, then.

Comment: @et_l What Overleaf marks as dubious is not necessarily so. Only running LaTeX will tell you whether the input is faulty. And that input isn't.

Comment: @egreg thanks. As noted in my edit - I understand now that this is not a Latex problem but rather an Overleaf one (hence the added "in Overleaf" to the title). I still would like to keep working in Overleaf without this annoying error - so I would still like a solution. I'm emailing Overleaf about it - hopefully they can fix the bug. In the meantime if there's a workaround I would like to know, so I'm leaving the question here, with the added info specifically saying I need it to work in Overleaf. I'll try adding an `Overleaf` tag as well, if such a tag exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a LaTeX error and Overleaf is at fault marking it as a mistake.

You can use `minipage` and this won't trigger the bad behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A &= B \\
&= C && \text{Having }x_2+5\text{ here is fine} \\
&= D && \parbox[t]{5cm}{
          But having it here cannot 
          be achieved via dollars $x_2+5$ around it} \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
A &= B \\
&= C && \text{Having }x_2+5\text{ here is fine} \\
&= D && \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
          But having it here cannot 
          be achieved via dollars $x_2+5$ around it
          \end{minipage} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. Checked it in my testing project as well and it really solves the Overleaf problem. Hope Overleaf will fix their editor's bug regarding this (I emailed them about it, including a link for this thread, when I first realised it was their editor's bug rather than a LaTex issue so hopefully they are aware of it).

Answer (score 2):

Putting the math between `$` seems to work fine when both text and math are inside a `parbox`, which is a good solution for managing long texts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        A &= B \\
        &= C && \text{Having}\ x_2+5 \text{ here is fine} \\
        &= D && \parbox[t]{5cm}{
            But having it here \textbf{can}
            be achieved via dollars $x_2+5$ around it} \\
%#ERROR: unclosed open { found at $    %            unexpected $ after \begin{align*}
                &= E && \parbox[t]{5cm}{
                    nor via the same trick as the text command, 
                    i.e. }\  x_2+5\ \parbox[t]{5cm}{ like so}\\% x_2+5 outside the parbox, so already in math mode
                &= F && \parbox[t]{5cm}{
                    and even if I give up and want it formatted 
                    as text it decides for me to change to math 
                    mode all the text $x_2+5$ appearing after it} % changed <<<<<<< 
            \end{align*}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: On your code there is not $ for the second x_2+5.

Comment: @Sebastiano It is outside of the parbox, so already in math mode.

Comment: Excuse me very much....+1.